# Is there a single word that means “helpful and interesting”?

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

I’ve been reading a lot of applied psychology and find myself frequently
describing an exciting idea as “both interesting and helpful”, to connote that the idea is intellectually fascinating and also has clear and interesting implications for how it could be applied to one’s own life, and/ or personal growth, and/ or understanding self or others. Is there a single word - or a better phrase - that connotes both of these things?

Comment: One for the opposite is 'neither use nor ornament'.

Answer (score 1):

A single word that may come close is

**noteworthy** (adj.)

> A fact or event that is noteworthy is interesting,
> remarkable, or significant in some way. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/noteworthy)

> Worthy of attention, observation, or notice; notable, remarkable.
> (OED)

---

> The given word '**noteworthy**' means worth paying attention to,
> interesting or significant. [EduGorilla; *RBI Office Attendant
> Recruitment Exam Preparation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/RBI_Office_Attendant_Recruitment_Exam_Pr/lcoyEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=noteworthy%20means%20helpful%20interesting&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> When he asked her if the information was **helpful** she answered him
> that the only **noteworthy** info was the location of the body and the
> fact that the victim had not been killed on the spot. [Hélène Lapaire
> Justus; *My Secret*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/My_Secret/kI5E5WYL58MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22noteworthy%22%20information%20is%20helpful&pg=PA395&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> The improvement in the work of these two girls was **noteworthy**, helping
> considerably in the increased production of the group. [*Silbley
> Journal of Engineering*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Sibley_Journal_of_Engineering/vV-cAlmmQWYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=noteworthy) p.127 (1918)

> Work on the pragmatic uses of language in journalism was
> **noteworthy** in that it not only allowed scholars to consider journalism through one of its most obvious, proven, and patterned
> manifestations—language—but it also helped make journalistic work
> comprehensible by connecting it to the broader uses of language.
> [Barbie Zelizer; *Taking Journalism Seriously*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Taking_Journalism_Seriously/3t3AesTWP7YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20noteworthy%20and%20helped&pg=PT152&printsec=frontcover) (2004)

Comment: Noteworthy doesn’t quite work in this context because it has a quite impersonal tone.  The context here is personal growth and development; so “helpful and interesting” implies personally helpful to me and others, in application to our own lives.